# Match a pattern in line not followed by any character

Tags: regex

With regex, I'd like to make sure all variables are defined.

So the regex should match all strings (whatever the number of spaces) that are followed by an equal sign and are not followed by any character on that line. But the equal sign can be followed by spaces, tabs anything other than characters.

[Here's the **opposite** of what I'd like to get](http://regexr.com/42fbc): `([^\s]+).*=.*([,\S]+)`

```js
// SELECT THESE ONES
const okOne =    
const okTwo=
okThree=
var okFour=

// DON'T GET THESE ONES
const badOne = "badOne"
const badTwo=  "badTwo"
badThree=3
var badFour=$s
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple, try the following; `^.*=\s*$`

Within each line `^$`, starts with anything up to an equal sign `.*=`, should have nothing but empty space or just nothing till the end of line `\s*`

[check online](https://regex101.com/r/tG703B/2)

Comment: @Thefourthbird still is valid, since he won't be having such broken double `=` cases, otherwise the property file would be invalid and matching any empty new lines is still valid since it does match an unset property in the end

Comment: I've been looking for hours for a way to do something similar, was about to ask a question when the suggestion came up. That's why people jump to ask without even look for others answers, sometimes it takes some time to find it! Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `^.*?=\W*$`

[regexr.com/42fbi](http://regexr.com/42fbi)

It will match anything before the equal sign (non greedy), then `=` and then any non-character (`\W`).

Answer (score 1):

You could match any character non greedy until the first equals sign. Then match 0+ times a space or a tab.

`^.*?=[ \t]*$`

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `.*?` Match any character non greedy
- `=` Match literally
- `[ \t]*` Character class which matches 0+ times a space or a tab
- `$` End of the line

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6WwM35/2)